# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I don't kwnow why invalid syntax.

```
data[g in data.G.str.split(",") if (g.strip() == "H") else pass]

^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks

Comment: Syntax errors can be in the lines above the error. A missing paren for example. Can you add the lines above this one for context?

Comment: Provide some data and explain your logic.  I suspect there is a much better approach to this problem than what you are trying to accomplish with this errand statement.

Comment: Is that really where the syntax error is? `else pass` doesn't make sense. Pass isnt a value.

Comment: I have a "data" with a column named G. it has string separated by ",". I need check in each row if contains a specify string, not only contains. that's why I need to use split.

Comment: Please edit your question according to the general guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `pass` in this way.

I think what you want is:

`data[(g.strip() == "H") & (g in data.G.str.split(","))]`

see here to understand the syntax: [Python Ternary Operator Without else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199757/python-ternary-operator-without-else)