# Is this proper use of a ternary operator

Tags: python

I want a short form the remove an element from a list and use the following:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> val = 3
>>> a.remove(val) if val in a else None
>>> a
>>> [1, 2, 4]
>>> val = 10
>>> a.remove(val) if val in a else None
>>> a
>>> [1, 2, 4]
```

Obviously it works but is it a proper use of a ternary operator?

Comment: It will work, but it's not pythonic. Ternaries are intended for use in expressions where the value is needed, not as a substitute for `if` statements.

Comment: What's wrong with the shorter `if val in a: a.remove(val)`?

Comment: @Barmar, I believe that's just bad formatting, unless you meant a new line of course...

Comment: `val in a and a.remove(val)` is at least a shorter misuse of a construct.

Comment: @Nineteendo no new line needed. It's valid

Comment: @roganjosh: Convention: C0321 - More than one statement on a single line.

Comment: @Nineteendo doesn't make it syntactically invalid

Comment: IF you're okay with removing *ALL* occurrences of the item from the list, then the "pythonic" way of doing this would be `a = [x for x in a if x != val]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Ternary Operator Without else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199757/python-ternary-operator-without-else)

Comment: Both `a.remove(val) if val in a else None` and `if val in a: a.remove(val)` do two linear scans of `a` when `val` is present. That's redundant, at best. Pythonic, as I understand the term, is `try: a.remove(val) except ValueError: pass` (on four lines). Better: make `a` a set and just write `a.discard(val)`, which is O(1) instead of O(len(a)), and which is the desired no-op if `val` is not there.

Comment: @rici valid, unless you need to represent duplicate values

Comment: @roganjosh: then you use a collections.Counter

Comment: @rici indeed in my case going with a set is the most appropriate as the list is a unique set of indexes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a Pythonic use of a ternary.

Let's put the question aside for a second and look at:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(a.remove(2))
```

Well, that gives us `None` because `.remove()` works in place.

Now, thinking about a ternary; why might we want that? Usually it would be due to some decision over an assignment:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = "foo" if a[0] == 1 else "bar"
print(b)
```

If we apply this kind of model to your ternary, you will *always get `None`*. It's somewhat similar to using list comprehensions [for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(a.remove(2) if 2 in a else None)
print(a.remove(10) if 10 in a else None)
```

If the operation is always going to `return None` anyway, then any reader of the code is going to ask why you even bothered with the ternary. There must be some underlying reason, right, because you have an `else` case even when it's effectively a no-op because the value wasn't found. But I, as a reader, can't determine whether the condition was `True` or `False` because I'm going to get `None` either way.

As stated in the comments, you can do this in one line:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
if 2 in a: a.remove(2)
print(a)
```

Your intent here is more clear because there is no need for a fall-back ternary condition. Even so, chasing lines like this is *pointless*, but it's better than the ternary.

Not only that but, as @nineteendo points out, you'll have issues with linters by compressing the `if` check to a single line: see [CO321](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/multiple-statements.html) and, more generally, [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Comment: Could you at least mention that multiple statements are against the conventions?

Comment: Another arguably improper way of doing this: `val in a and a.remove(val)`  (Though I thought it was kinda cool) https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199948/11865956